# Factorial Word Problem

Tags: problem-solving

Here is the problem:

"The traditional French greeting is to kiss the other person on each cheek.
So, when two traditional French friends meet, one kisses the second on
both cheeks and the second person kisses the first on both cheeks.
a. Make an In-Out table where the In is the number of friends meeting
and the Out is the total number of kisses. Your Ins should go from 1
through 6 at least.
b. Write a formula for the total number of kisses, k, in terms of the
number of friends, f."

So I think that the formula has something to do with factorial but I cannot find a formula. I have a table with points (1,2), (2,6), (3,24), (4,120), (5,720) and (6, 5040). Where x is the number of friends you meet with and y is the total number of kisses. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The counts do not seem to be right. If there is only $1$ person in the group, there are $0$ kisses.

If there are $2$ people in the room, there are $4$ kisses (A kisses B on both cheeks, $2$ kisses, B reciprocates, $2$ more).

Now look at the case of $3$ people, A, B, and C. Again we can make an explicit count. For A and B, we have $4$ kisses. For A and C, $4$ more, and finally for B and C, $4$ more, for a total of $12$.

If you have a certain amount of patience, you can deal with $4$ people, A, B, C, and D. First A exchanges kisses with B, C, and D. That's $12$ kisses. Now B, C, and D exchange kisses with each other. That's the case of $3$ people, which we have already solved! So they account for $12$ more, for a total of $24$.

Now deal with $5$ people, A, B, C, D, and E. First A does the kiss thing with B, C, D, and E. That's $16$ kisses. Then B, C, D, and E exchange kisses. That's already been computed, it is the $4$ people case, we get $24$. so the total is $16+24$. which is $40$.

Finally, deal with $6$ people, A to F.  First A exchanges kisses with the $5$ others, total $20$. Then the remaining $5$ exchange kisses, total $40$. The sum is $60$.

To get a general formula, there are many approaches. We could follow up on our analysis above. Or we could start again.

For every **pair** of friends, there will be $4$ kisses. Do you know a simple formula for the number of **pairs** there are if there are $f$ friends in the group?

If you do not, here is a way of counting. We will call the people by the even more boring names $1,2,3,4,\dots,f$.
Let us first count the number of **ordered pairs** $(x,y)$ that we can form. The first person in the ordered pair can be chosen in $f$ ways. For **each** of these ways, the second person can be chosen in $f-1$ ways. So the total number of ordered pairs is $f(f-1))$. But this is not the number of plain pairs, for it counts (Alicia, Beti) as different from (Beti, Alicia). The fix is simple: divide our count of ordered pairs by $2$. So the number of **pairs** of people is
$$\frac{f(f-1)}{2}.$$

Now make your formula. To check for any mistakes, compare what your formula predicts with our explicit counts above.

Comment: I got the equation $\frac{4f(f-1)}{2}$ which simplifies to $2f(f-1)$ which is what @EnYu got. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. As I suggested, you can check it against the explicit calculations in the first part of my solution.

Comment: If $f$ was $1$ then there would be $0$ kisses? Shouldn't there be $4$?

Comment: @StevenN I think the confusion here is that your $f$ and our $f$ is off by one. You seem to be referring to $f$ as the number of _your_ friends while we refer to $f$ as the _total_ number of friends (i.e. total number of people).

Comment: If the number of friends (people) in the room is $1$, there will be no kisses: traditionally, French people do not kiss themselves.  It is **conceivable** that "number of friends" is intended to refer to people other than oneself. If $x$ is the number of people other than yourself in the room, then the number of kisses is $2x(x+1)$.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up, this makes sense now :).

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite related to the factorial but to the number of pairs you can form with the friends. If there are $N$ friends then how many unique pairs of friends are there? Each pair will exchange $4$ kisses so your total number of kisses is $4$ times the number of pairs.

**Edit**: Some elaboration.

Consider the choose function $\binom{n}{r}$. If we have $f$ friends and we need to find out the number of pairs, then that's equivalent to choosing $2$ out of the $f$ friends. Therefore the number of pairs is given by $\binom{f}{2}$. The binomial coefficients are normally given by factorials, but in this case it simplifies drastically.
$$\binom{f}{2} = \frac{f!}{(f-2)!2!} = \frac{f(f-1)}{2}$$
The number of kisses is $4$ times this value, so the total number of kisses is given by
$$k = 2f(f-1)$$

Comment: Would the formula be k=4f? Since a pair of friends will exchange 4 kisses?

Comment: Is $f$ the number of friends or the number of pairs? Do you know how to find the number of pairs?

Comment: f would be the number of friends, and I do not know how to find the number of pairs.

Comment: Do you know about the _choose_ function and binomial coefficients then?

Comment: Is the choose function n Choose r (nCr)?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Think about what $f\rm{C}2$ represents.

Comment: That would be the number of pairs of friends, but how would I turn that into an equation? Wouldn't the equation involve factorials?

Comment: Technically the choose function is defined as factorials. But this case is simple so it's not needed. Let me add something to my answer.